# How to calculate VaR price space according to PRIIP flow diagram

Tags: value-at-risk, priips

My question is regarding the European regulation on standardizing the information in the KID's for PRIIPs. (https://esas-joint-committee.europa.eu/Publications/Technical%20Standards/JC%202017%2049%20(PRIIPs_flow_diagram_risk_reward).pdf)

In Part 3 (calculation of MRM for category 3 PRIIP) I can´t figure out what to do in Step 6. I also can´t find any Information on VaR price space at all. The provided example in the flow diagram unfortunately stops at step 5.

Is there anybody who can help me with this problem?

Kind regards

Comment: VaR (Value at risk) can be $VaR_{RETURN SPACE}$ or $VaR_{PRICE SPACE}$. One is based on returns over a period, the other on prices at the end of the period.

Comment: "The VaR in price space shall be calculated from a distribution of PRIIP values at the end of the recommended holding period. The distribution shall be obtained by simulating the price or prices, which determine the value of the PRIIP, at the end of the recommended holding period. The VaR shall be the value of the PRIIP at a confidence level of 97,5 % at the end of the recommended holding period discounted to the present date using the expected risk-free discount factor from the present date to the end of the recommended holding period."

Comment: OTOH: "To calculate the VaR [in] Return Space using the Cornish Fisher expansion, you need the history of observed returns of the PRIIP. The returns are calculated by taking the natural logarithm of the price at the end of the current period divided by the price at the end of the previous period."

Comment: Well yes, but the diagram says, that I need to calculate the value of the product and then sort that. To go on in the calculation, a percentage return is needed and not the value (€) of the PRIIP.